# Retirement after reaching 40 credits, non-us citizen but green card holder

Tags: united-states, retirement, international, social-security, permanent-resident

I am a green card holder and I have been working for a US company since January 2011. I am 52 years old and I plan to stop working when I  reach 40 credits at the age of 55 in July of 2021. I do not plan to request benefits until I am 63. After I stop working I will be living in another country and it is likely that I will no longer  have my permanent resident card.

QUESTIONS:

1. Will I be eligible for retirement benefits if I am neither a US citizen nor a permanent resident?
2. Since I currently have less than  40 credits, I can't check the normal Social Security calculator. Is there any way to get an estimation of what my benefits will be if I do get benefits? (My earnings are maxed to the tax limits imposed by SS)

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the [2017 benefits worksheet](https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10070.pdf) (pdf) to get an estimate of the retirement benefits you would get with only 40 credits but a high salary.

Comment: Thanks, the calculation was useful. Any idea in terms of what happens if I would no longer be a permanent resident?

Answer (score 3):

According to this Social Security Administration [page](https://www.ssa.gov/international/countrylist1.htm), nonresident aliens from these countries can continue to receive benefits no matter how long they live outside the United States:

> If you are a citizen of one of the countries listed below, your Social
>   Security payments will keep coming no matter how long you stay outside
>   the U.S., as long as you are eligible for the payments.
>
> - Austria
> - Belgium
> - Canada
> - Chile
> - Czech Republic
> - Finland
> - France
> - Germany
> - Greece
> - Hungary
> - Ireland
> - Israel
> - Italy
> - Japan
> - Luxembourg
> - Netherlands
> - Norway
> - Poland
> - Portugal
> - Slovak Republic
> - Spain
> - Sweden
> - Switzerland
> - United Kingdom

If you're not a citizen of one of these countries, you should consult with a immigration or tax specialist to find the best avenue to ensure that you can collect the Social Security benefits that you've earned.

Comment: But see this page, which seems to contradict the first page mentioned.  https://www.ssa.gov/international/payments.html?tl=0

Answer (score 0):

> Since I currently have less than 40 credits, I can't check the normal Social Security calculator. Is there any way to get an estimation of what my benefits will be if I do get benefits? (My earnings are maxed to the tax limits imposed by SS)

One can use the [Quick Calculator](https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/quickcalc/), the [Online Calculator](http://www.ssa.gov/retire2/AnypiaApplet.html) or the offline  [Detailed Calculator](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/anypia/anypia.html): they can give an estimation of the benefits even if one hasn't reached 40 credits yet. Link to all the calculators: https://www.ssa.gov/oact/anypia/index.html

E.g. with the [Quick Calculator](https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/quickcalc/):

[image]

outputs:

[image]